# How $|f(a) |= e^{-i\alpha}f(a) ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some confusion in maximum modulas theorem , my confusion marked in red  box given below[image]

How  $|f(a) |= e^{-i\alpha}f(a) ?$

My thinking : here we have taken  $\alpha = Arg (f(a))$

By definition of Arg we have

$arg(f(a))= -i \log \frac{f(a)}{|f(a)|}$

Now if u put the value $\alpha=arg(f(a))$

Then $|f(a)|= e^{-i \log \frac{f(a)}{|f(a)|}}f(a)$

Im confused that How  $|f(a) |= e^{-i\alpha}f(a) ?$

Comment: They have simply used the polar representation of a complex number. Any non-zero complex number $z$ can be written as $z = re^{i\theta}$ where $r = |z|$ and (one of the choices for) $\theta$ is $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $z$ any complex number, $ z = |z|.e^{i\alpha} $, where $\alpha$ is the argument of $z$.
Then using $z = f(a), f(a) = |f(a)|.e^{i\alpha}$. Rearrange to get your answer.